# Unable to set property in different class ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

In my first class (Secen1ViewController.h) I have property:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL myBoolean;
```

In my second class (Secen2ViewController.m) I have imported Secen1ViewController.h and have declared property:

```
@property (strong) Secen1ViewController *parent;
```

I have also initalized property in ViewDidLoad:

```
 _parent = [[Secen1ViewController alloc] init];
```

and then when button is pressed I set the property:

```
 self.parent.myBoolean=YES;
```

There are no errors displayed but myBoolean from Scene1 is not set to yes.

Comment: The usual reason for this complaint is that you're referencing two different copies of your object.  Each `alloc` operation creates a DIFFERENT object, and you can't set a value in one and expect to read it in another.  (Sorry if this isn't your problem, but it's amazingly common.)

Answer (score 0):

First add `@class Secen1ViewController (.h)` and `#import Secen1ViewController in (.m)`

set your myBoolean property to

```
@property (assign,nonatomic) BOOL myBoolean;
```

and `@synthesize it in (.m)` and use it in you `Secen1ViewController`

```
self.parent = [[Secen1ViewController alloc] init];
self.parent.myBoolean = YES;
```

Comment: CalculatorViewController was a typo but not in my code I have now edited the question. I tried adding @class Secen1ViewController and I already have import but there is no effect. I don't know if it's relevant but these to classes are already connected with Segue.

Comment: how about _parent.myBoolean = YES;? And how you know that is Yes or NO? with NSLog? Please more detail.

Comment: I tried it but nothing changed. And yes NSLog says that Boolean is set to NO.  NSLog(_myBoolean ? @"Yes" : @"No");

Comment: I edited my answer. set your bool property with (assign,nonatomic).

Comment: I am really confuse about your code. Why _myBoolean? should be like that NSLog(self.parent.myBoolean ? @"YES" : @"NO")?

Comment: Ok so self.parent.myBoolean in Secen2ViewController is YES but that doesn't seem to affect original property in Secen1ViewController.

So myBoolean is property of first class and second class is trying to set it to YES.

Answer (score 0):

Did you synthesize your boolean variable? Apparently it's possible that you didn't declare

```
@synthesize myBoolean = _myBoolean;
```

in your implementation file.

Comment: I tried with that as well although in ios6 there is no need to synthesize unless I am using custom getter and setter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this code:

```
_parent = [[Secen1ViewController alloc] init];
```

with this code:

```
self.parent = [[Secen1ViewController alloc] init];
```

And make sure you synthesize all the properties.

Comment: Is that Secen1ViewController inherits from UIViewController, right?

Comment: It does work fine, maybe you missed my previous comments but self.parent.myBoolean in Secen2ViewController is YES but that doesn't seem to affect original property in Secen1ViewController. So myBoolean is property of first class and second class is trying to set it to YES.